# A problem with web scraping using python ,BeautifulSoup and pandas 'read_html'

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Thank you for the helpers !

I am scraping a table of data about covid19 and push it into a pandas data frame , it was working until this morning .

That the code :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'

req = requests.get(url)

page = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

table = page.find_all('table',id="main_table_countries_today")[0]

print(table)

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```

This morning I starting to get the next error :

```
ValueError: No tables found matching pattern '.+'
```

Can you please help me figure it out ?

Comment: This code is working fine for me. Returning a list of dataframes.

Comment: I am getting the same error on different ide ,

can you please show me what you get from the code ?

Comment: Install covid19 library. It is better `pip install COVID19Py` [https://pypi.org/project/COVID19Py/](https://pypi.org/project/COVID19Py/)

Comment: @ZurHanin - Not sure whats the issue. Can you check the lib versions for lxml and html5lib, once?

Comment: Thank You ,your api is a really good source , but its importune to me to understand what i did wrong in my code ..

Comment: @Anshul , 

html5lib==1.0.1 ,

 lxml==4.5.1

Comment: @ZurHanin These look fine. Same versions are working fine for me. Sorry, not sure what else could differ :(.

Comment: @Anshul , the things is that I run on heroku server and on my PC and in both machines I get the error ..  it's really interested me what is different on your machine

Comment: what pandas version you running?

Comment: hi there - thanks for the code: i have runned the code and it is returning a list of dataframes `<table class="table table-bordered table-hover main_table_countries" id="main_table_countries_today" style="width:100%;margin-top: 0px !important;display:none;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="1%">#</th>
<th width="100">Country,<br>Other</br></th>
<th width="20">Total<br>Cases</br></th>
<th width="30">New<br>Cases</br></th>
<th width="30">Total<br>Deaths</br></th>
<th width="30">New<br>Deaths</br></th>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the last line to: `df = pd.read_html(str(table), displayed_only=False)[0]`
The table header at the url has changed its style attribute to style="width:100%;margin-top: 0px !important;display:none;".  Previously it did not have the 'display' tag set.

Comment: Thank you very very much , your solution work !

can you please guide me on which subject i can read for deep understanding  about 
that subject ?

Comment: Pandas read_html simply provides the option of processing elements with display:none set (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).  See more on the display property here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp.  By the way, your original code works again today (May 31), so they changed again.